# valueHelpRequest method not get fired in sap.m.input by enabling showValueHelp="true"

Tags: sapui5

I want to show password by clicking help indicator in control sap.m.input.

As per code valueHelpRequest method must fired but not fired when clicking help indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution : 
var oInput = this.getView().byId("idName"); oInput.attachValueHelpRequest(function(){
   console.log("You click on value helper.")
});

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine for me. Share some code.
[jsbin sample](http://jsbin.com/cekimibigo/1/edit?html,output)

js view code

```
createContent: function(oController) {
                // button text is bound to Model, "press" action is bound to Controller's event handler
                return new sap.m.Input({text:'{/actionName}',press:oController.doSomething,showSuggestion:true,showValueHelp:true,valueHelpRequest:oController.onVHR});
            }
```

Comment: I am using xml view.

Comment: I got solution. solution is :var oInput = this.getView().byId("idName"); then oInput.attachValueHelpRequest(function(){ console.log("You click on value helper.")});